# PowerShell Freeze on File System Copy

Tags: powershell

For some when I run this command in PowerShell, it succeeds up to a certain point:

```
Copy-Item  S:\schools\$question C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\schools\$question -Recurse -Verbose
```

Integrated with my current script, this line takes the files from **S:\schools\$question** and copies them to **C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\schools\$question**. This works fine on some folders, and then just stops running on other ones. On the one's that it stops running on, PowerShell seems to be using 50% of my CPU resources, whitch should never happen as I'm just copying files.

Again, as always, any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include any files/folder names on the one that it seems to be hanging on. Possible issues could be because the path is too long (i.e. 260+ chars). or that the file contains special characters (i.e. $)

Comment: There are no special characters in the file, or file name. I tried copying a folder named /r/ to C:\Users\$env:username\Desktop\schools\$question and it still didn't work. Stopped running at C:\Users\bettiom\Desktop\schools\r\images\resources\Thumbs.db

Comment: Two thoughts. First has a module installed a proxy function for Copy-Item? Run `Get-Command Copy-Item | fl *` to see if its the command from `Microsoft.PowerShell.Management`.  Second, how does robocopy behave with these dirs?

Comment: Agree with Keith - try RoboCopy, you'll get more feedback. Another thought would be permissions. Files under C:\Users\... are typically protected. Does your script run with necessary Admin rights?

Comment: Long story short, I'll have to test these things out on Wednesday. Thanks for the feedback, guys. And yes, I have the necessary permissions to copy/modify all these files/folders.